# Alert Shows Different on Iphone than on Ipad

Tags: ios, swift

I want my iphone alert to look like the ipad alert

[image]

code:

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Appcoda", message: "Message in alert dialog", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: {(alert :UIAlertAction) in
        print("Delete button tapped")
    })
    alertController.addAction(deleteAction)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(alert :UIAlertAction) in
        print("OK button tapped")
    })
    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.frame

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What can I add to the code above to have the iphone alert look like the ipad alert?

Comment: Because of the small screen area, Apple choose to display UIAlertView on the bottom.

Comment: You need a [custom UIAlertView](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ios+custom+UIAlertView)

Answer (score 0):

Alert are only able to be shown from the bottom of the view/window on the iPhone. Try using an 3rd party alert view. Look here: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/